# SQL Server 2012 Express connection successful but error occured during login

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-2012-express

I get the following errors accessing my local SQL Server 2012 Express data using VB.Net 2012.

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The specified network name is no longer available.
>
> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.

It seems like the connection is not being released because I have a function with the exact same code (except parameters) and it works 3 times, but on the 4th I get an error like above.

Code:

```
Public Function LookupSQRIDX(Lotnumber As String, TableToUse As String, IDXFieldToUse As String, LotField As String, LotMatch As String, SearchLine As String) As String
    Dim sConnection As String = "Server=MARIO\VSQL;Database=LEASE;User Id=cookieuser;Password=oreo;"
    Dim objCommand As New SqlCommand


    objCommand.CommandText = "Select top 1 " & IDXFieldToUse & " From [dbo].[" & TableToUse & "] where " & LotField & " like '%" & LotMatch & "' and line = '" & SearchLine & "' order by " & IDXFieldToUse
    objCommand.Connection = New SqlConnection(sConnection)
    objCommand.Connection.Open()
    Dim objDataReader As SqlDataReader = objCommand.ExecuteReader()
    Try
        Dim NumCols, NumRows As Integer
        Dim RowNum As Integer
        Dim MyArray = ""
        Dim Map1LastLot = "", Map2LastLot = ""

        If objDataReader.HasRows Then
            NumCols = objDataReader.FieldCount - 1
            Do While objDataReader.Read()
                RowNum = RowNum + 1
                MyArray = objDataReader(0).ToString
            Loop
            NumRows = RowNum
            objDataReader.Close()
            objCommand.Dispose()
            Return MyArray
        Else
            objDataReader.Close()
            objCommand.Dispose()
            Return ""
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error: " & ex.Message)
        objDataReader.Close()
        objCommand.Dispose()
        Return ""
    End Try

    objDataReader.Close()

    objCommand.Dispose()

End Function
```

Comment: it works 3 times and throws an exception on 4th every time you run it?

Comment: Yes it does. Except this time when I got the error I attempted to load SQL Server Management Studio and it also failed until I stopped my running VB application. Pretty sure it's a connection based issue. I'm not running in windows authentication mode because this will be a remote app.

Comment: I guess you are using ADO.NET. Can you share you connection string and    code snippet which is responsible for establishing the connection?

Comment: You have no code that calls the `Dispose()` on the connection object you create here?

Comment: I thought objCommand had the connection object in it.

Comment: Do i need to do an objCommand.Connection.Close before I do the Dispose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added the following (using the tip provided by hvd) and the problem went away. Evidently you need to close and dispose of the connection even though it is already contained in the objCommand being disposed.

```
       objCommand.Connection.Close()
       objCommand.Connection.Dispose()
       objDataReader.Close()
       objCommand.Dispose()
```